# Codeception 4.1 not working with PhpStorm 2020.1 EAP

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, codeception

PhpStorm Testing with Codeception﻿

I have configured codeception to work with phpstorm by following the steps at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-codeception-framework.html

Codception version 4.1.2
PHPUnit version 8.5.2
PHP version 7.4.2

Test cases are getting run when manually execute via terminal by running ”/vendor/bin/codcepet run” but when run them via PhpStorm I am getting this error

[image]

```
:/usr/local/bin/php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/codeception.php run --report -o "reporters: report: PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter" --no-interaction -c /opt/project/codeception.yml tests/unit/UserTest.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.2
Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run API test cases it works but still exit code 1 is returned

```
/usr/local/bin/php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/codeception.php run --report -o "reporters: report: PhpStorm_Codeception_ReportPrinter" --no-interaction -c /opt/project/codeception.yml tests/api/LoginCest.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.2
Powered by PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 

LoginCest: Login with success..............................................Ok
LoginCest: Login with fail.................................................Ok

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I could not find any records in the IDE.log about this issue. How can we investigate or fix this issue.

Comment: Since it's an EAP build of PhpStorm (not yet released/not many people have tried it, so it may have some issues here and there)... I suggest to **contact JetBrains support directly** (either from the entry in `Help` menu or via "Submit a request" link on their forums/site: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731